# Why does the VS Watch window show ContentItem > base > ContentItem > base all the way down?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I understand the basics of class hierarchies and inheritance. So, I don't understand the class hierarchy that the Watch window shows for a ContentItem object.

[image: It's turtles all the way down.]

It appears to say that ContentItem inherits ContentItem inherits ContentItem... all the way down to infinity. What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@insta got it almost right. ContentItem derives from DynamicObject, which derives from nothing (it only implements an interface). Under any object that is of a different concrete type than that of the property under which it is, the debugger shows first the same object as its most concrete representation. For example, if you look at the record property of a content item, you'll see that it is of type ContentItemRecord, but if you deploy it, you'll see under it something labeled [ContentItemRecordProxy]. VS seems to be doing something special about dynamic types however, where it seems to get confused about what the type of base should be, so it shows you the actual object under [Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentItem], which itself has a base class, and so on to infinity and beyond. You can safely ignore this weird behavior.

Comment: `DynamicObject` appears to derive from `Object`, which is a `class` not an `interface`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. What do you mean by, "it only implements an `interface`)."

Comment: All objects derive from Object. VS doesn't bother showing you that, and I didn't bother mentioning it. Sorry if that was confusing.

Answer (score 2):

I think in this specific case, you're seeing something unique to Orchard.

I downloaded the source, and ContentItem is a dynamic object that exposes a field called ContentItem.  It's likely you're seeing a heirarchy that's just

`PageBase > Pages > Admin Page > Components > Component > Login Component > Text > etc`

I think this object tree was deeper than your patience.  For the most part, you are correct -- the "base" will take you to the superclass.

Answer (score 2):

The type is shown in the third column of the watchlist, which MS kindly shoved far off to the right so you hardly notice it. The second column is "Value" and does get these repeated values.

[image]